# Question about Solana codebase — what is the reason for saving V0_0_1 in enum ReplicaBlockInfoVersions?

Tags: geyser

I found ReplicaBlockInfoVersions enum in src/geyser_plugin_interface.rs (snipped under the text). Where oneof is V0_0_1. I found no usage of ReplicaBlockInfoVersions::V0_0_1 or ReplicaBlockInfo in codebase.
What is the reason of saving unused enum?

```
pub enum ReplicaBlockInfoVersions<'a> {
     V0_0_1(&'a ReplicaBlockInfo<'a>),  
     V0_0_2(&'a ReplicaBlockInfoV2<'a>),
}
```